# Rails (Activerecord) - Can't make query with joins and global sum without duplicates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I'm using a query with multiple user-set filters in order to show a list of invoices in a Rails app. One of the filters adds a where condition on a column of a separate table, which needs a double join in order to be accessible (estimates -through projects-).

```
  scope :by_seller, lambda {|user_id|
    joins(project: :estimates)
    .where(estimates: {:user_id => user_id}) unless user_id.blank?
  }
```

Additionally, I use Rails' aggregate method "sum" in order to find out the total amount of the invoices, @invoices.sum(:total_cache), where total_cache is a cached column in the database specifically designed to perform this kind of sum in a performant way.

```
@invoices.sum(:total_cache)
```

My problem is, given the fact that I need a double join in order to access Estimates through Projects, and that each Invoice belongs to a Project, BUT a project can have many Estimates, the join operation results in duplicate records, so my Invoices table shows some of the invoices many times (as many as the number of estimates its project has). This results in an invoices table with duplicate records, and in an incorrect sum value, as it sums some of the invoice totals N times.

The filtering behaviour is just fine, as my intention is to filter by the user who made ANY of the estimates in the invoice project. However, the issue is that when I try to avoid the duplicates by adding a group('invoices.id') -the way I always solved such situations-, the final sum operation won't return the total sum of the invoices' total, but a grouped sum of each one of them (totally useless).

The only workaround I've found is to include the group clause and perform the sum in pure ruby code, treating the collection as an array, which IMHO is terribly inefficient, as there are tons of invoices:

```
@invoices.map(&:total_cache).inject(0, &:+)
```

Is there a way I can obtain a unique ActiveRecord collection of Invoices without duplicates in a way I can then call the aggregate sum method and obtain a total calculated by Postgres?

Of course, if there is something wrong in my base idea I'm completely open to hearing it! It's quite a complex query (I simplified it for the sake of the question here) and there can be many approaches I'm sure!

Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how much "slower" or "faster" this is than doing the sum in ruby code. But if you want to still retain an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object, then you can do something like below. I reproduced your setup environment in a local Rails project.

```
user = User.first

Invoice.where(
  id: Invoice.by_seller(user.id).select(:id)
).sum(:total_cache)

# (1.2 ms) SELECT SUM("invoices"."total_cache") FROM "invoices" WHERE "invoices"."id" IN (SELECT "invoices"."id" FROM "invoices" INNER JOIN "projects" ON "projects"."id" = "invoices"."project_id" INNER JOIN "estimates" ON "estimates"."project_id" = "projects"."id" WHERE "estimates"."user_id" = $1)  [["user_id", 1]]
# => 5
```